# A telling set of graph statistics

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If you were to come across a graph DB which contained data you had no knowledge about, what sort of questions would be useful to get a feel for it? A sort of schema & summary...

Some examples I've been using already:

- how many nodes & relationships are there?
- what distinct node & relationship types are there?
- what are the ways nodes connect (node type - rel type - node type) ?
- which nodes have the largest number of connections (the super hubs) ?
- ...

I know there are some semantically-specific questions depending on the data, but the ones above are generic, and regarding graph patterns, networks, communities and connectivity - are there any other "general" graph questions that would help provide a nice overview of the graph?

Answer (score 1):

As one metric, Neo4j comes with a nice "What's related and how" query in the favorites in the sidebar:

```
// What is related, and how
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
WHERE labels(a) <> [] AND labels(b) <> []
RETURN DISTINCT head(labels(a)) AS This, type(r) as To, head(labels(b)) AS That
LIMIT 10
```

This shows you a distinct list of relationships and the types of labels they connect.

Comment: I mentioned I use this already - "what are the ways nodes connect (node type - rel type - node type) ?". It misses important points such as superhub nodes, the most common relationships, etc...

Comment: Yeah, certainly, I didn't mean for it to be a complete answer, but it was a bit too large to fit into a comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

A good schema will tell you everything you need to know. It will show you the structure, the datatypes, the relationships and the relationship types.

Other than that I might request some sample data, 100 rows or so from each table.

Below i have included a diagram of [Crows Feet Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Crow.27s_foot_notation) and their meanings.

[image: Crows Feet Notation]

Comment: I often don't have a schema, which is why I want a list of cypher queries to investigate the graph. And a sample of 100 rows will give you an idea of the specifics between 100 nodes, but not an overview of the global graph.